# Is there a method in facebook API for Android to handle incorrect credentials?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-apps, android-facebook

Facebook manager has callback which has only the following methodS:

```
 public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult){}
 public void onCancel() {}
 public void onError(FacebookException e) {}
```

Is there a method that lets the developer know that user has entered invalid credentials?

Comment: `onError` is for such purpose

Comment: When I debugged, the control didn't hit onError when wrong password was entered. Moreover facebook redirected me to browser. i wonder how the control is transferred back to the app!

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't tell you whether the user entered their credentials correctly or not. All the SDK tells your app is whether the user authorized your app.

That means getting an `onError()` callback means that the user did not authorize the app, but that may be for multiple reasons. Just one of which could be that the user did not authenticate themselves to Facebook correctly and then decided to abort the "Login with Facebook" flow.